# How can I store a sql query into a variable, not the result?

Tags: mysql

Hello I am doing a script that needs to consult the results of another query Q1, this Q1 is used in a lot of other queries for example

```
select * from a,
where id in (Q1)

select * from b,
where id in (Q1)

select * from c,
where id in (Q1)
```

The problem is that Q1 can change a lot, so I want to store it in a SQL variable in order to avoid changing three times instead of one.

Is this possible?

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Had you tried to store into a temp table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample you can try to [CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html) let your query be simply.

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `temp_Q`(
    `t_id` INT NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO temp_Q (t_id)
SELECT id
FROM Q;


select * from a,
where id in (SELECT t_id FROM temp_Q)

select * from b,
where id in (SELECT t_id FROM temp_Q)

select * from c,
where id in (SELECT t_id FROM temp_Q)
```